# E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-ros-base

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I following the tutorial to install roetic on my Debian 10 buster system. I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-ros-base
```

When I run `sudo apt update`, ros does appear in the update list.

```
"packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu buster InRelease"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353145/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-noetic-ros-base/) by [Dave_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/55212/dave_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-05-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nullspace](https://answers.ros.org/users/57539/nullspace/) on 2020-08-10**:
same issue ,anyone help me to solve this problem please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just tested this in a `debian:buster` Docker container (on `amd64`) and following the installation instructions results in `apt` wanting to install 1126MB of packages for me when I ask it to install `ros-noetic-ros-base`. So it seems to work.

What is the output fo `uname -rvmp` on your machine?

Note that Buster only gets binary packages (from the ROS buildfarm) for the `amd64` and `arm64` architectures (see also [wiki/noetic/Installation](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation)). If you're attempting to install it on other platforms (such as `armhf`) you cannot install it using `apt`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/55212/dave_ros/) on 2020-05-25**:
The output of uname -rvmp is

```
4.19.0-9-armmp-lpae #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2 (2020-04-29) armv7l unknown
```

...armv7l is 32 bit processor. *face palm*

**Comment by [alexspi13](https://answers.ros.org/users/57492/alexspi13/) on 2020-08-11**:
I have armv71 too, there is a guide that clearly explain the way to install it, but I have problem, to install one package. If you find a way to install it please tell me because I m trying 4 days